# Problema na hora de popular elementos no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estava fazendo um projeto de um chat em php, com ajax, porém meu código ele não insere nada ao banco de dados, só que eu não faço ideia do que é, e antes de pensarem que não pesquisei, já tentei trazer a variável do js para php, mas não consegui, tentei mudar o comando do sql, mas também não foi. Por isso venho pedir uma ajuda de vocês, não é nada mastigado, pois eu já fiz, apenas esse é o problema (O banco não popula).

Desde já obrigado pela atenção.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Sistema de Chat</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>

</head>

<body>

<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = "Henrique Nunes";

?>

<div id="tela">
    <h1>Bem vindo ao chat</h1>

    <div class="tela_chat">

        <div id="chat">

        </div>

        <form method="POST">
            <textarea name="mensagem" cols="30" rows="7" class="textarea">

            </textarea>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

    /*  -- JQUERY NO TEXTAREA --
        Essa parte o jquery vai pegar o número da tecla digitada
        e se o número for 13(enter) ele vai enviar
    */

    $('.textarea').keyup(function (e) {

        if ( e.which === 13 ){ //Se a tecla for igual a 13(enter)
           $('form').submit(); //Envie pra o formulário o que foi digitado
       }

    });

    $('form').submit(function () {

        var mensagem = $('.textarea').val();

        $.post('manipuladores/mensagens.php?
action=enviarMensagem&mensagem='+ mensagem, function (
            response
        ){

            alert(response);

        });

        return false;

    });

</script>



</body>


</html>
```

config.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbnome = 'chat';
$dbusuario = 'root';
$dbsenha = '1234';

try{
    $db = new 
PDO("mysql:dbhost=$dbhost;dbname=$dbnome","$dbusuario","$dbsenha");
}catch ( PDOException $e){
    echo ("<label style='color:red;'> Erro: </label> ".$e->getMessage(). "
<br><p style='color:red;'>Recomenda-se buscar na internet o código do erro.
</p>");
}



?>
```

mensagens.php (dentro da pasta manipuladores)

```
<?php

include_once ('../config.php');

switch ( $_REQUEST['action']){
case "enviarMensagem":

    //global $db;

    $comandoSQL = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mensagens SET mensagem = ?');
    var_dump($comandoSQL);
    $comandoSQL->execute([$_REQUEST['mensagem']]);
    var_dump($comandoSQL);

break;
}
```

Informações da base de dados
    nome: chat;
    tabela usada: mensagens;

mensagens é composta por:

```
id: PK, AI
usuario: VARCHAR(45)
mensagem: TEXT
data: TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está no construtor da classe `PDO`. Você está passando o valor `dbhost` para indicar o servidor do banco de dados, porém o correto é `host`. Dessa forma:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbnome;host$dbhost","$dbusuario","$dbsenha");
```

Outra coisa, evite passar a mensagem via `GET` e depois capturar com a variável global `$_REQUEST`.

Utilize dessa forma:

```
$.post("manipuladores/mensagens.php?action=enviarMensagem", {
    mensagem: $('.textarea').val()
}, function(response) {
    alert(Response);
})
```

E no `PHP` você pode capturar dessa forma:

```
$comandoSQL->execute([$_POST['mensagem']]);
```

Comment: Alterei desta forma que falou, mas ele ainda não popula. Teria como eu forçar algum erro pra que me dê uma saída com o var_dump() para ficar mais claro e entender o que está acontecendo ?

Comment: @HenriqueN.Mendes verifique se `PDOException` retorna algum erro; Verifique também os dados de sua conexão com o banco de dados; Você também pode utilizar `$db->errorInfo();`

Comment: Quando adiciono var_dump($db->errorInfo()); ele me retorna isso no response:

    array(3){
 
 [0] =>
  string(0) ""
 [1] =>
  NULL
 [2] => 
  NULL

    }

Comment: @HenriqueN.Mendes dê um `var_dump` em `$comandoSQL->execute([$_REQUEST['mensagem']]);` e adicione `$comandoSQL->errorInfo();` após `execute()`

Comment: Dei um var_dump em $comandoSQL->execute([$_POST['mensagem']]); e ele retornou na resposta "bool(false)" e quando fiz o $comandoSQL->errorInfo(); ele retorna isso: array(3){

 [0] =>
  string(5) "3D000"
 [1] =>
  int(1046)
 [2] =>
  string(20) "No database selected"
}

Comment: Eu não entendo, pois eu consigo conectar ao banco de dados...

Comment: @HenriqueN.Mendes Verifique o conteúdo da variável `$dbnome` e se o banco de dados com o valor de `$dbnome` existe.

Comment: Os nomes estão iguais $dbnome = 'chat'; e o nome do banco no phpmyadmin está chat também. Que estranho

Comment: @HenriqueN.Mendes Alterei minha resposta, se possível verifica novamente a forma de conexão.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72332/discussion-between-henrique-n-mendes-and-valdeir-psr).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não esteja inserindo no banco por isso: `INSERT INTO mensagens SET mensagem = ?`. 
Ao invés de SET use : `INSERT INTO mensagens (mensagem) VALUES (:MENSAGEM);`

```
$comandoSQL = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mensagens (mensagem) values (:MENSAGEM)');
$comandoSQL->bindParam(":MENSAGEM",$_REQUEST['mensagem']);
$comandoSQL->execute();
```

Comment: Também não deu certo ;-;

Comment: Aparentemente não está usando bindParam() para o valor da mensagem.
Tente fazer assim:

$comandoSQL = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mensagens (mensagem) values (:MENSAGEM)');
$comandoSQL->bindParam(":MENSAGEM",$_REQUEST['mensagem']);

Comment: Nada... Eu inclusive dei um var_dump($comandoSQL->execute()); e ele me retornou na resposta bool(false). Assim como os comentários da resposta acima da sua, é como se a base de dados não estivesse conectada...

Comment: Estranho. Eu editei minha resposta com o trecho correto. Eu repliquei teu código aqui no meu localhost, e dessa forma que eu citei está inserindo no banco... Você chegou a dar um SELECT diretamente no phpMyAdmin? Porque no alert() do JS realmente não está mostrando.

Comment: Sim, não há nenhum registro :( Vou tentar em outro PC, não é possível...

Comment: Tentei aqui no meu outro pc e não popula também ;-;